# Can I change the sysinfo export language?

Tags: windows-7, logging, export, english, sysinternals

I just noticed that when I export the sysinfo logfile for diagnosis that all the stuff in there is in my national locale! This is of course bad if I want help from international / English speaking members like here. Thus I wonder:

**Is there any way to force Windows (7) to put it out in English?**

I am highly disappointed in Windows that it lacks this kind of crucial functionality...